# Laravel - Email Attachment Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have three files a user can upload but the issue is if an image isn't attached it throws an Undefined variable error, because nothing is being passed through, the main issue is that attachments are defined via the url, so when I add a null value or a '' to it, it throws a timeout error.

is there a better way/approach to tackling this?

```
if ($request->file('img_1')) {
            $file = $request->file('img_1');
            $image_name1 = time()."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();

            if ($file->move('uploads/quote', $image_name1)) {
                $enquiry->img_1 = $image_name1;
                $enquiry->save();
            }
        }else{
            $image_name1 = '';
        }
```

Here's the function I used after this

```
function ($message) use ($request, $image_name1, $image_name2, $image_name3) {

                $name_input = $request['name'];
                $company_name = 'Test';

                $message->to($sendto_email, '')->from('alerts@testing.com', 'Quote')->subject('New Quote from ' . $name_input )->attach('uploads/quote/' . $image_name1)->attach('uploads/quote/' . $image_name2)->attach('uploads/quote/' . $image_name3);
        });
```

EDIT:
It's mainly the $message-to part, finding a way to not add the ->attach IF a specific image isn't selected/isn't set

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use array-variable to put it in a use to avoid 'undefined error':

```
$images = [$image_name1, $image_name2, $image_name3];

function ($message) use ($request, $images) {

    $name_input = $request['name'];
    $company_name = 'Test';

    $message->to($sendto_email, '')->from('alerts@testing.com', 'Quote')->subject('New Quote from ' . $name_input);

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $message->attach('uploads/quote/' . $image);
    }
```